# Subset vectors of dates within a list

Tags: r, list, date, conditional-statements, subset

I have a list of vectors of dates. I want to subset each vector within that list to leave only the dates which fall within a certain time interval in all those vectors.

```
l <- list(a=seq.Date(as.Date('2017-01-01'),as.Date('2017-01-31'),by = 1), 
          b=seq.Date(as.Date('2017-01-09'),as.Date('2017-02-28'),by = 1), 
          c=seq.Date(as.Date('2017-01-20'),as.Date('2017-03-31'),by = 1))
```

I tried doing this, but I'm missing smth

```
library(lubridate)
cond<-lapply(l,FUN=function(x) ymd(x) %within% interval(ymd("2017-01-05"), ymd("2017-02-01")))
l[cond]
```

Comment: Almost there, try instead `cond<-lapply(l,FUN=function(x) x[ymd(x) %within% interval(ymd("2017-01-05"), ymd("2017-02-01"))])`

Comment: Note that you don't need lubridate: `lapply(l, function(x) x[x >= as.Date("2017-01-05") & x <= as.Date("2017-02-01")])`

Comment: Awesome, thank you!